# Prestashop unit price decimal configuration

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, commerce

I've got a problem with my prestashop v1.7.2

I want to set the unit selling price with 4 decimals. In prestashop I can set this configuration but all my price are affected. I just want the unit selling price...

I try to modify my product controllers to change number format but prestashop has the last word.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change it from `/translations/cldr/`.

Edit the file `main--xx-XX--numbers`, where `xx-XX` is the language you want to change, this mean, if you have more than one language, you need do this change for each one.

Locate a code like this `"accounting":"\u00a4#,##0.00;(\u00a4#,##0.00)","standard":"\u00a4#,##0.00"`, note, this is for `en-US`, so, depending on the language could change a little bit, but the `"standard"` will always be immediately after the `"accounting"`

And now just add the 4 digits, like this `"accounting":"\u00a4#,##0.0000;(\u00a4#,##0.0000)","standard":"\u00a4#,##0.0000"`

NOTE: After the change you need clear all the cache, including the browser cache.

Comment: Thank's @Rolige but I already do this. This modification affect all of my prices. I just want to do that on my unit selling price. I don't know if it possible..

Comment: This change is visible of course, if you only want the estimates to be made based on 4 digits but does NOT affect the visualization, you can change the `Number of decimals` in the: BO > Shop Parameters > General